# node.js + azure sql database

Tags: node.js, azure

i'm struggling with the [microsoft's node.js sql client.](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver)

I've installed it, without any errors using the guide at the github page, and everything works perfect locally. but when i use git to push it to azure, i get the error:

```
Native sqlserver module not found. Did you remember to run node-gyp configure build?
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Unable to load shared library C:\DWASFiles\Sites\bid110\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\msnodesql\build\Release\sqlserver.node
```

I've also looked at [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/sql-database/) guide, even though some parts is outdated. I've also cheked that all the files are uploaded to the server. the node_modules/msnodesql and node_modules\msnodesql\build\Release\ folders with all its subfolders are there as well.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if your msnodesql is x86 or x64. If your local machine was x64 with x64 Python, and you installed msnodesql through `npm install msnodesql` then you should get a x64 version. But on Windows Azure Web Site your application will be running in x86, so you might need to a x86 version of msnodesql. You can install through NPM from a x86 machine, or you can download the compiled version at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29995

I also have a blog post about this hope that helps. http://blogs.shaunxu.me/archive/2012/09/18/node.js-adventure---when-node.js-meets-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: ah, great. I have 64 bit windows/python so i guess that's the problem. Thank you for your enlightening answer :)

Comment: Edit: i tried what you suggested, downloaded the 32bit version from the webpage. but then i cant run local or at azure, getting the error "did you remember to run node-gyp configure build". When i run the command (32 bit python) it works locally again, but it still says the same thing on azure. 32 bit python/msnodesql installers are not enough?